# LTspice to WRspice netlist conversion

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice

How do I convert the .asc file in LTspice to a netlist file for WRspice? Any recommendations? Is there any direct and easy way to do this? If not, how can I edit the .asc file to the respective netlist to generate a schematic in WRspice?

Comment: In LTSpice, you can go to View -> SPICE Netlist and then copy it somewhere.

Comment: I've written LTspice .ASC file parsers explicitly for the purpose of feeding the schematic to a completely different schematic generator. But I don't recommend taking that approach to generate a schematic in WRspice. Your thought about just grabbing a netlist is far more portable and a lot easier to do. As @Renan points out, you can just ask LTspice for the netlist. Unless the netlist in LTspice includes some custom devices or parameters that WRspice can't handle, it's likely you can port it over to WRspice, easily, as it should also accept the standard SPICE netlist.

Comment: thank you for the information.